# スマートフォン（iOS、アンドロイド等）で縦向きに撮影した動画の横向きへの設定方法

Tags: ios, android, php, html, 動画

お世話になっております。何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。

php、html、javascript、mysqlを利用した動画投稿アプリの作成を企画しております。

そのアプリにスマートフォン（iOS、アンドロイド等）で縦向きに撮影した映像を投稿した際に、
php、html、javascript、mySql、あるいはそのアプリに他のソフトウェアを組み込み、映像を横向きに設定し直す方法などはありますでしょうか。通常どのようにされているのでしょうか。

どうかご教示よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 「映像を横向きに設定し直す」というのは、縦長の解像度を持つ動画を、横長の解像度に回転して保存する、あるいは、回転して表示するということですか？

Comment: nekketsuuu様、ご返信感謝致します。理解していないで、質問してしまい申し訳ございません。ネットで検索すると、投稿用の動画はスマートフォンで横向きにして撮影すべしなる記事を見ますが、仮に縦向きに撮影した場合、それを横向きに撮影したものと同様、あるいは縦向きに撮影したがために生じるであろう弊害を取り除くような設定がもしあるなら、あるいは同様のケースで例えばメジャーなサイト様がやられているようなことをご教示頂ければ有難く存じます。

Comment: 質問というのは理解できないことに対して行うものなので、お気になさらないでください :)　その「撮影したものと同様」の「同様」がどのようなことであるのかを具体的になさるのが良いと思います。逆にその仕様が具体的にどういうものなのかが記述されないと答えにくいです。単に「よしなにしたい」ではなく、どういう課題を想定していて、克服したいのかを書き下してみてください。

Comment: 関連ブログ記事: [「YouTubeのiOS版アプリ、縦長動画の全画面表示に対応しました」](https://www.gizmodo.jp/2017/12/youtube-ios-video.html) -- Gizmode

Comment: nekketsuuu様、ご多忙の中お時間を頂きまして、また関連ブログ記事のご紹介など感謝いたします。本件とりあえず時間をかけながらやって参ろうと存じます。ありがとうございます。